# Linking a IBAction to multiple buttons?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ibaction

If I link an IBAction to multiple buttons, if multiple calls to this IBAction where done simultaneously would it cause interference or a crash. Will each one have to wait for the other, or is it concurrent?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User interface events (button presses, etc.) are processed one-by-one by the main thread. Unless you are specifically calling your IBAction method from multiple threads, it will *not* be executed simultaneously. In other words, actions triggered by user interface events are run sequentially. Each action will complete before the next begins.

There is no need to write separate (but identical) methods for your buttons because the event-by-event processing of the main thread will ensure that the action method is called sequentially, once for each button press. If you write a separate action method for each button, those action methods will *still* be executed one at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know what I was thinking. So multiple calls to the same IBAction wont crash, it will just queue them. Thanks. I can reduce the code size then.

Answer (score 1):

They'll have to wait for each other to finish.

Comment: I will keep it as is, 1 for each button. Wanted to reduce code :(

Comment: Wanted to reduce code? Writing the same thing twice is probably more code than writing it once...

Comment: ??? I wanted to reduce code by linking one IBAction to many buttons instead of 1 for each? Thanks to the answer above by James this is solved.

Comment: I guess we both misunderstood each other ;)